# Почему при нажатии клавиши пробел, нажимается кнопка на UI?

Tags: unity3d

Делал игру авто симулятор, и вот под конец моей работы произошла странная особенность, при первом запуске игры все хорошо, при смене авто(кнопка UI на Canvas) меняется авто, можно ехать, но если нажать пробел(Кнопка ручника) срабатывает кнопка(кнопка UI на Canvas) для смены авто! Если нажать клавишу ехать вперед, авто едет, если в этот момент нажать пробел, нажмется кнопка(кнопка UI на Canvas) для вызова режима паузы, и только после того как вызовется меню паузы, я его закрою, все работает должным образом. Все опять повторится если я опять нажму кнопку(кнопка UI на Canvas) для смены авто!
Еще утром все работало хорошо, и тут такое... И еще если сменить авто и щелкнуть мышкой по экрану в любом месте, тогда все будет в порядке и пробел будет работать как ручник для авто. Что я делал:

1. Переустанавливал EventSystem.
2. Пытался найти вызов кнопки пробел(единственный вызов для активации ручного тормоза, при его отключении проблема остается).

Кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: В играх меню пользуются не только мышкой, но и клавишами или креставиной геймпада. Выбранный UI элемент срабатывает на нажатие пробела, согласно настройке импутов `EventSystem`. UI элемент можно лишить такой возможности указав `Navigation: null` или изменить значение текущего выбранного UI элемента на null `EventSystems.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблему решил сменив у кнопки Navigation на None, но все благодаря твоему комментарию я разобрался в чем дело. По поиску в яндексе "EventSystems.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null)" выводит на форум где у людей теже проблемы, и как они их обходят.